# Can't *update* pycharm educational

Tags: python, ide, installation, pycharm

I am a Ubuntu 16 user and I installed pycharm educational 2 at my computer.
A few days ago while starting the app I received the notification that there's am update : version 3
So I downloaded the file(.tgz) from from the developer website and tried to install the update. I can only extract the file instead of actually installing like in Windows wizards
Can you explain me what went wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unpack the archive, go to `bin` folder and run `.sh` script.

Comment: This option will only run the pycharm.sh as one time run,but not as installation

Comment: @Yoda Extracted files are ready to work. What do you expect from installation process?

Comment: My interest is to upgrade the installation of my already installed pycharm educational v2

Comment: @Yoda How did you install PyCharm initially?

Comment: Can't remember what I did

Comment: @Yoda Import previous installation settings on the first run of extracted `pycharm.sh`, update desktop entries (if exists) to point to new pycharm, remove folder with old pycharm :)

Comment: It's not what I asked. I wish to install the update on the original application as we do on a regular basis in Windows when we upgrading

Comment: @Yoda If possible, PyCharm shows `Download and update` button (or smth like this). After this button has been clicked, PyCharm downloads patch and updates itself. But sometimes it's not possible and PyCharm shows only `Download` button which leads to manually updating.

Comment: The second option it's what I see. you can only download the update file . and then run the .sh file without any installation. The reason why it's so important is because after a proper installation you actually get an icon in the applications section

Comment: @Yoda As it was mentioned above, it's possible to update .desktop files to point to new pycharm (http://askubuntu.com/a/434319) or drop old folder and put new one on its place.